# Topojson segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, topojson

I'm trying to convert a shp file of [Texas neighborhood boundaries](http://www.zillow.com/static/shp/ZillowNeighborhoods-TX.zip).  I installed topojson with no errors.

I run:

```
  $ topojson -o texas_hoods.json --id-property NAME ZillowNeighborhoods-CA.shp -p --v
  $ [1]    9533 segmentation fault  topojson -o texas_hoods.json --id-property NAME ZillowNeighborhoods-CA.shp -p
```

Any theories on why I'm receiving a segfault?  I was able to convert to topojson in the past.  I recently reinstalled homebrew etc., but can't figure out what's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a node 0.10.31 issue. See this: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8208 .

Comment: I reverted to node 0.10.30 and the segfaults went away.